# SMO SQL job creation and clustered servers - as simple as I think it is?

Tags: sql, sql-server, smo, sql-agent-job, sql-agent

As part of our deployment process, we use SMO to create SQL jobs programmatically on the server as part of the configuration needs to be dynamic, and it also makes the entire process automatic for us. This has been working well for the past few weeks on a single SQL server setup.

However we are shortly moving to a clustered SQL server environment, with one cluster controller and 2 nodes. From the research I've done, we just need to point our SMO code at the cluster server, the job will be created, and everything will work as it did in the non clustered environment.

But is this true? Will the cluster controller handle this correctly? Such as ensuring the job is replicated on both nodes? And ensuring it only runs once, and not on each node?

I don't have any test infrastructure available yet to check on, but would be good to get a heads up that it is going to be as easy as I think it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an Active/Passive cluster you’ll still only have 1 msdb that each node can see.  So yes it is as easy as you think.
Basically for this just forget about the nodes.  Point your SMO connection at the cluster instance name and let it run.

Comment: Thanks Bruce... was essentially what I thought/was hoping! I'm going to have a test over the next couple of days - will accept your answer assuming all goes well :).

Comment: Can confirm everything worked as @Bruce suggested. The job was duplicated across nodes, but only ran once on the active one.